# batch file to open a website and auto-fill forms

Tags: forms, batch-file, autofill

Am trying to open a website and filling a form, from "echo off" till "del %command%" is working fine but from the second example website it's not working which related to filling forms!

```
@echo off
set command=C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\GMAIL.VBS
start https://www.example.com/sign-in
echo Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") > %command%
echo Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") >> %command%
echo Do Until Success = True >> %command%
echo     Success = objShell.AppActivate("Google Chrome") >> %command%
echo Loop >> %command%
echo WshShell.SendKeys "E-mail" >> %command%
echo WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}" >> %command%
echo WshShell.SendKeys "Password" >> %command%
echo WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}" >> %command%
ping 192.0.2.2 -n 1 -w 5000 > nul
start %command%
ping 192.0.2.2 -n 1 -w 1000 > nul
del %command%
start https://www.example2.com/my-account/new-order/
echo WshShell.Sendkeys "Name"
echo WshShell.Sendkeys "{TAB}"
echo WshShell.Sendkeys "City"
echo WshShell.Sendkeys "{TAB}"
echo WshShell.Sendkeys "City"
exit
```

Comment: well, probably because just echoing something does not fill something other. Compare the code for the first site (until `del %command%` with the code for the second site.

Comment: Thanks Stephan for your reply, even i compared but it's not filling forms, i just need answer if by batch file we can filling forms in a specific websites or no?

Comment: depends on the site. But for your second site, your batch file does not even attemt to do something.

Comment: it's clear but on thing what is the exact command for filling forms, or do i have to change or replace any command?

Comment: the "filling" is done by a VBscript, because batch can't do it. Build a VBscript for your second site analogue to the first one. Please don't ask us to do it for you - it's really easy. If *then* you have a specific problem, come back and we will help you.